# Is there a way to pass a variable into a class like you do a function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, class, variables, swiftui

I have a class that looks like this

```
class ObjectManager: ObservableObject {

     @Published var current = Parser(path: "path")[0]

}
```

However, when I call this ObjectManager I want to be able to change the path so that it then eventually goes to a different view without having to rewrite all that code that configures the view.

I tried to use

```
class ObjectManager: ObservableObject (path: String) { 

//code

}
```

but that doesn't work.

I then tried to use

```
@State private var state : String
```

But then I got this error 'Cannot use instance member 'path' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available'.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should read more about what classes are, and their relationship to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add explicit constructor with default path

```
class ObjectManager: ObservableObject {

     @Published var current: TYPE_OF_CURRENT_HERE      

     init(path: String = "path") {
        self.current = Parser(path: path)[0]
     }
}
```